# join three tables using Laravel Eloquent Join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This is my table structure

```
announcement_catagory
 
 `id`
 `company_id`
 `category_name`
 `employee_id`
 `created_date`
```

announcemet

```
`id`, 
`company_id`, 
`employee_id`, 
`category_id`,
`title`, 
`announcement`, 
allow_comment`,
announcement_date`,
view_count`,
status`

announcement_comment
    `id`,
    `company_id`, 
    `employee_id`,
    `category_id`,
    `title`,
    `announcement`,
    `allow_comment`,
    `announcement_date`,
    `view_count`,
    `status`
```

and my models are

```
class Announcement extends BaseClientCompanyModel {

protected $table = "Announcement";

}

class AnnouncementCategory extends BaseClientCompanyModel {

        protected $table = "Announcement_Category";
}


class AnnouncementComment extends BaseClientCompanyModel {

    protected $table = "announcement_comment";

}
```

I need to get the announcements based upon the company id with their category and number of comments , i dont have an idea from where should i start